# Combining 2 columns in to 1 column

Tags: php, sql

```
        $GETyears_SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(start_date) as yearlist FROM pt_assign ";
        $GETyears_SQL .= " UNION ";
        $GETyears_SQL .= "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(end_date) as yearlist FROM pt_assign ";
        $GETyears_SQL .= " ORDER BY yearlist ASC ";
```

my question is how to get distinct year from 2 columns `start_date` and `end_date` date columns in to one column?
I got this working with above **sql** statement, but seems it's not the right way do this! will there be any error/complication if I used this statement?

I have searched here and none of them work the way I want.

Comment: your UNION statement seems a good and ANSI standard way to achieve this, I don't see any issue with it.What's the RDBMS?

Comment: Server : MySQL
Server version: 5.6.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Actually, the `UNION` command already applies a data distinction, so you don't need to specify the `DISTINCT` command in the queries... to `UNION` all data without distinction, just append the keyword `ALL` to the keyword `UNION`...

Comment: For mysql your solution is as good as it gets. For DBMS that supports LATERAL a more efficient solution exists.